# How do I derive Feynman rules for vectors involving derivatives?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, feynman-diagrams, vector-fields

Suppose I have a term in the Lagrangian: $$\cal{L} \equiv (\partial_\mu B^+_\nu)  B^{-\mu} A^\nu $$, where $B^\pm$ are charged massive vector particles and $A$ is photon. Now, how can we derive the Feynman rule for the following vertex:

[image]

My guess for the vertex is: $ p_{+\mu} \delta_{\alpha \nu} \delta_\beta ^\mu \delta_\mu ^\nu $, what I did is replaced the partial derivative with the momentum $p_+$ and then have taken derivatives w.r.t all the fields involved.

I want to know clearly the procedure for the derivation of Feynman rule for this case at hand.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially it. Just take into account that it's usually a better idea to symmetrize this kind of thing ($\mathcal L = \frac12 (\partial_\mu\mathcal B_\nu^+) \mathcal B^{-\mu} \mathcal A^\nu - \frac12 \mathcal B_\nu^+ (\partial_\mu\mathcal B^{-\mu}) \mathcal A^\nu - \frac12 \mathcal B_\nu^+ \mathcal B^{-\mu} (\partial_\mu\mathcal A^\nu)$) and then apply your procedure.

Comment: @DavidVercauteren, Thanks, actually I didn't provide a nice Lagrangian, I had just shown a piece of it just to learn the procedure but I agree on symmetrization. So, you are saying my procedure is correct for the piece of Lagrangian that I provided ?